# PHP - Unexpected T_VAR when including a variable

Tags: php, include

I get this error when I try and include a variable from an external php file:
**Unexpected T_VAR on line 1**

Here is my external php code:

```
<?php var dbStr = 'host::,username::,password::,database'; ?>
```

Here is the PHP file that is including it:

```
if($_POST['admincreate'] == "ok")
{
include('db.php');
$info = explode("::,", dbStr);
$con=mysqli_connect($info[0],$info[1],$info[2],$info[3]);
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO admins (id, user, pass)
VALUES ('" . $_POST['user'] . "', '" . $_POST['pass'] . "',0)");
}
```

It works if I change the code to

```
if($_POST['admincreate'] == "ok")
{
$dbStr = 'host::,username::,password::,database';
$info = explode("::,", $dbStr);
$con=mysqli_connect($info[0],$info[1],$info[2],$info[3]);
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO admins (id, user, pass)
VALUES ('" . $_POST['user'] . "', '" . $_POST['pass'] . "',0)");
}
```

But I need the included file.

If I change the included file to

```
<?php $dbStr = 'host::,username::,password::,database'; ?>
```

I get this error:
**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in .../db.php on line 1**

And I find that the external php file has changed to

```
<?php  = 'host::,username::,password::,database'; ?>
```

**How do I include this string properly without it giving me an error?**

P.S. The external php is generated by the main php file use fopen and fwrite, also the actual values of host, username, password, and database have been censored just because I feel better that way.

Thanks in advance,
-p0iz0n

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: Your PS appears to be more important to your question than anything else in the body: you are trying to generate PHP using PHP somewhere, and it is going wrong (as you say, your "external" PHP file doesn't look how you expect it to). The problem is not in anything you've shown us, it's in the process that's writing the "external" file.

Comment: No, but I tested it by manually writing the external file, and it changes it reguardless

Comment: @Daniel Where's the vulnerability? How can I fix it?

Comment: @ρσݥzση try reading http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: @ρσݥzση What is the "it" in the phrase "it changes it regardless"? PHP will not change a file when you `include` it, so the obvious culprit is your code which dynamically writes that file.

Comment: Incidentally, I just noticed a typo in your first code snippet: you have `explode("::,", dbStr)` instead of `explode("::,", $dbStr)`

Comment: Thats not a typo, that is because the file included says var dbStr nor var $dbStr. And to answer your earlier question: I realised before I include the file I rewrite the external php. The external php is meant to have the var name in it, but for some reason once it has written the file, it leaves the var name out, I dont know why...

Comment: @ρσݥzση As others have pointed out, `var dbStr` doesn't mean anything in PHP, and passing `dbStr` rather than `$dbStr` to `explode()` won't do anything useful at all. If you want us to help with the problems of the file being rewritten incorrectly, please either edit the question to include the relevant code, or open a new one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`var` is not valid PHP

```
<?php var dbStr = 'host::,username::,password::,database'; ?>
```

should be

```
<?php $dbStr = 'host::,username::,password::,database'; ?>
```

Interestingly enough you have it right in your second example.

Comment: Thanks! :) Do you have any idea why it keeps changing to `<?php  = 'host::,username::,password::,database'; ?>` ?

Comment: That I don't know as that is just *really* bizarre. :/